# webix dynamic loading via php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, webix

Webix DataTable

I have it reading from a php script, but it only ever grabs the first dataset.  The php script accepts &page= [current page] and &size= [number of records]
I can only get it to pagify if i give all the records to it. (which won't work because thats about 1 gig lol.

Here is an example of the data. [i've limited it to 2 results]

```
{
"count": 84,
"count_filtered": 84,
"rows": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "accountName": "test",
        "status": 2,
        "notes": null,
        "globalIframe": null,
        "globalPostback": null,
        "postBackDelayMS": 0,
        "streetAddress1": null,
        "streetAddress2": null,
        "postalCode": null,
        "city": null,
        "countryCode": null,
        "stateProvince": null,
        "accountManager": 1,
        "paymentCycle": 0,
        "minimumPayment": 100,
        "paymentType": 0,
        "paymentDetails": null,
        "created_at": "2017-12-02 19:03:41",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-02 19:03:41"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "accountName": "ta",
        "status": 2,
        "notes": null,
        "globalIframe": null,
        "globalPostback": null,
        "postBackDelayMS": 0,
        "streetAddress1": null,
        "streetAddress2": null,
        "postalCode": null,
        "city": null,
        "countryCode": null,
        "stateProvince": null,
        "accountManager": 1,
        "paymentCycle": 0,
        "minimumPayment": 100,
        "paymentType": 0,
        "paymentDetails": null,
        "created_at": "2017-12-02 19:07:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-02 19:07:49"
    }
],
"listable": []
```

}

Here is the JS I use to pull that data into the webix data table.

```
var datatable = webix.ui({
    view:"datatable", 
    container:"dataTable",
    datafetch:20,
    datathrottle: 500,
    loadahead:100,
    autoheight:true,
    autowidth:true,
    yCount:10,
    autoConfig:true,
    columns:[
{ id:"accountName",    header:"Affiliate Name",  width:tableWidth}
],
on:{
    onBeforeLoad:function(){
        this.showOverlay("Loading...");
    },
    onAfterLoad:function(){
        this.hideOverlay();
    }
},

url:function(details){
    return webix.ajax("/affiliates/data?1").then(function(data){
        var js = data.json();
        var new_js = [];

        for (key in js['rows']){
            new_js.push({
                id:js['rows'][key].id, 
                accountName:js['rows'][key].accountName
            });     

        };

        return new_js;
    })
},
navigation:"true",
pager:{
    container:"dataPager",
    size:10,
    group:4

}
}); 


datatable.attachEvent("onDataRequest", function(start, count, callback){     //count
    var view = this;
    console.log("GETTING DATA");
    webix.ajax().get("/affiliates/data?size=10&page="+start/10).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);

    this.parse(data.json());
     var js = data.json();
    var new_js = [];

    for (key in js['rows']){
        new_js.push({
            id:js['rows'][key].id, 
            accountName:js['rows'][key].accountName
        });     

    };
    return new_js;
})
    return false;
})
```

I've spent about a week trying to figure this out, so be gentle. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it.

```
var datatable = webix.ui({
    view:"datatable", 
    container:"dataTable",
    datafetch:25,
    datathrottle: 500,
    loadahead:0,
    autoheight:true,
    autowidth:true,
    yCount:25,
    autoConfig:true,
    columns:[
{ id:"accountName",    header:"Affiliate Name",  width:tableWidth, sort:"server"}
],
on:{
    onBeforeLoad:function(){
        this.showOverlay("Loading...");
    },
    onAfterLoad:function(){
        this.hideOverlay();
    }
},
url:'/affiliates/webixdata',
navigation:"true",
pager:{
    container:"dataPager",
    size:25


}
});
```

Then I changed the controller to match the server side response of 
https://docs.webix.com/desktop__plain_dynamic_loading.html#serversideresponse

This works better than the documented webix promise style function to manipulate the data in JS prior to it parsing.